# Characterization of Euclidean distance by means of functional equations

Tags: euclidean-geometry, functional-equations

I am trying to characterise the Euclidean distance $d:\mathbb{R}^{3} \times \mathbb{R}^{3}\to \mathbb{R}$, by means of functional equations. This is my current approach, but I am not able to fill the gaps and I would like to see rigorous references in the moulds of this approach.

Consider two points $P,Q \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and a right triangle $T$ with $\overline{PQ}$ as hypotenuse. For simpliticty, also consier $P$ as the origin of the system. Let's define $d(P,Q):= \overline{PQ}$.
By the properties of Euclidean geometry $d$ should satisfy the following functional equations

1. $d(P,RQ) = d(P,Q)$ (invariant under rotation with center in $P$).
2. $d(P, \lambda Q) = \lambda d(P,Q)$ (homogeneity of degree 1).

Let the coordinates of $Q := \{a,b,c\}$, by (1), we get

(1) $d(Q) = F(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$

Moreover, a family of homogeneous equation of degree 1 is given by

(2) $d(Q) = (|a|^p + |b|^p + |c|^p)^{1/p}$

by combining (1) and (2), we get $p = 2$, and the following formula for the distance

$d(Q) = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$

The question is: are (1) and (2) sufficient to characterize the Euclidean distance?If not, what are the other constraints on $d$?

[image: enter image description here|100]

Comment: It would be nice of you to indicate where you see the gaps. I, for example, see one here: $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt[3]{xyz}$ is surely homogeneous of degree 1, but is not of your form (2).

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected the text. Actually, my question is: are (1) and (2) sufficient to characterise the Euclidean distance? If not, what are the other constraints on $d$?

Comment: Then I think it is enough. Indeed, your first condition means that the distance is a function of $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$, and your second condition means that it is a linear function, $f=const\cdot r$.

Comment: I got It. Thanks!